# Android - Adding/Deleting/Updating records in Database by coding

Tags: android, database, image, connection, click

I am working on an application where I need to use Database, I particularly need to create a database by coding.

What I actually want is that When I click on the Image(an Icon that suggests the favorite songs of a user) the related audio file of that particular Image should be stored in database accordingly.

If anybody knows it, provide me a solution or code.

Thanks,
david brown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through this article/example: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842 , where you found exactly that you want. Try to implement the same in your way !!

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely want to use and SQLite database.  I think [Professional Android Application Development 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527) has a great example and skeleton code to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) guide. It will explain how to handle Databases in Android